# Typescript: How to compile only the files in a folder

Tags: typescript

The typescript docs state that in `tsconfig.json` we can control input files either with `files` where we list all files, or with `exclude`. I have all my source files in a `src` directory and only want to compile all files that are there (to a bifferent directory, `build`). I could `exclude` all other files and directories, but I might miss something. I don't want to manually add every file to `files`.

How can I specify to typescript that it should compile only the typescript files it finds in the `src` directory, and nothing else?

Comment: I read that `files` in `tsconfig` does not accept globs. Or was that wrong?

Comment: Nope, tested it, definitely does not accept globs

Comment: @jonrsharpe To clarify, I would like to specify this in `tsconfig.json` and not have to rely on passing any options to `tsc`.

Comment: Maybe that's an [Atom-specific thing](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md#filesglob), then. You can `exclude` whole directories, I think that's the only way to do this without exhaustively listing the `files` you *do* want to compile.

Comment: Yeah, found that, but it's not useful to me since I don't use atom.

Comment: tsconfig do accept globs since TS 2.0: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#glob-support-in-tsconfigjson

Comment: @Alex w8 what, is TS2.0 even out?

Comment: How come the typescript website says 1.8 is the latest?

Comment: TS 2.0 has not really made it out into the ecosystem yet, but it is a released stable version. Check it with npm for example.

Comment: Npm says 1.8 is the latest, but maybe they haven't packaged it there yet. I get it now.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, so it seems it's still regarded as a beta version. I thought it had passed that stage. But it should be ready to try out anyway :)

Comment: Ok, but thanks for telling me, glad to know it's coming

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For anybody who stumbles across this question like I did -

Just like `exclude`, directories can be included as well now.

I include just my src directory like this to compile only my src:

```
"include": [
"./src/**/*"
]
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [TypeScript documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), the only way to do this within `tsconfig.json` is either to:

1. Exhaustively list the files you *do* want to compile under `files`; or
2. Exhaustively list the files and directories you *don't* want to compile under `exclude`.

It does mention that files referenced by included files will also be compiled, so it's possible that 1. wouldn't have to list everything individually, but I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: even exhaustively listing the files, it'll go and transpile non-listed items they include.

Comment: @SephReed yes, that's the meaning of _"files referenced by included files will also be compiled"_.

Comment: If you add `noResolve` it solves this:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noResolve.